# Find a parametric equation and an equation in vector form for the lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I need to find a parametric equation and a vector form for the lines in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the equation

$$y = 3x - 1.$$

I know that the parametric and associated vector form is **x**=**p**+*t* **d**.

Could someone find a parametric equation and a vector form of this equation and could you explain how you found it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what $p$ and $d$ represent in that equation?

Comment: @amd Yes, I think **p** is a specific point on l (line) and **d** is a direction vector for l. Is this correct? Do you have additional information or another more clear explanation? :)

Comment: Perfect. I think that if you applied those definitions to the problem at hand, you’d be able to solve it yourself. Note, however, that the solution is not unique: there’s no such thing as “the” parametric equation of a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of a line is given by $m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.  In this case, since the slope of the line is $3$, we have the equivalent direction vector $\vec{d}=(\Delta x,\Delta y)=(1,3)$.  Since the given line has a $y$-intercept of $-1$, we know the line passes through the point with coordinates $(0,-1)$, and this gives us the final answer in its vector equation $$l:(x,y)=(0,-1)+t(1,3)$$
and in its parametric equations
$$\left.l:\begin{cases}
x=t\\
y=-1+3t
\end{cases}.\right.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! But why is **d** = (1,3)  (how do you find it) and why becomes 3x "0x"?

Comment: The slope of a line is the ratio between its vertical change to its horizontal change.  In the given line $y=3x-1$, since this is written in the form $y=mx+b$, by inspection we know that the slope is $m=3$.  On the other hand, $\vec{d}$, the direction vector, is written in the form $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$.  If the slope is $3$, this means that for every $1$ unit of horizontal change, there will be $3$ units of vertical change.  Therefore, $\vec{d}=(1,3)$.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation! One last question:  Why is x=0 (no x in the vector and parametric equation)?

Comment: A $y$-intercept of $b$ has the coordinates $(0,b)$ (you can confirm this for yourself by plotting it and trying to find its coordinates).